# Validate every route in angular 4 app against windows AD group using mvc web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api

I am creating intranet application using angular 4.

I want this application to be accessible only by users present in AD group named "IntranetAdmin". Also users should not be able to specific route of app directly if they are not part of AD group.

I have created a API endpoint which gets logged in used name and checks that name against AD group stored in web.config.

```
IPrincipal user = httpcontext.User;
string loginName = user.Identity.Name;
```

If logged in user is not member of AD group angular app should redirect user to a no access page. Also if user is not part of AD group then he should not be able to access any route by manually entering it in browser.

Comment: since Angular is entirely client-side this will be very hard to enforce, since the user can just alter the page source (using the browser tools) to remove the check with the API, and continue to the angular view anyway. Assuming the API also provides the data used by the Angular app, simply securing the _data endpoints_ which are server-side, rather than the Angular routes, will be easy and should hopefully provide the necessary security, since generally it's really the data rather than the view which is the sensitive thing. Security at the client-side is simply not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, i will secure the data endpoints based on AD group. But also want to have some mechanism to validate every route accessed.

Comment: since it's entirely client-side, you can't. Well, you can try, but you can't rely on it. Just assume that the user can (and malicious users will) do whatever they like if they want to. Once the page is downloaded into their browser, it's theirs to manipulate as they choose. They might even ignore your HTML and JS and just use a tool like PostMan to attack your API directly. Make sure that anything which is security-restricted is held server side and security is checked at the server every time a request is made to the API. That's the only way.

Comment: That way you could end up with scenario where the user manages to access the Angular view, but the view is unable to download any relevant data because they do not pass the security check on the API. So they just get an empty view, which shouldn't really cause any harm. You can actually see this architecture as an advantage, because in future if you change your GUI, or add an alternative GUI (e.g. mobile app, desktop app etc), all your security checks will already apply to the new GUI too.

Comment: okay. So best way is to authenticate very api request at server level? I can return some error code to angular is user is not part of AD group. How i can have a check every response from webAPI to look for specific error code, so that user can be redirected to no access page.

Comment: It's not just the best way, it's the only way. As per the REST principle, if you return a suitable HTTP status code, then your Angular app can easily tell what has happened - e.g. 403 Forbidden if the user does not have access, 400 Bad Request if the modelstate is not valid, 404 Not Found if the requested item does not exist etc. In an AJAX client receiving a non-success (i.e. not a 2xx or 3xx) status usually triggers a different callback. I don't know exactly how angular's AJAX libraries are structured but I'd expect this to be the case, I'd guess they might conform to the Promise API.